# Create model row in Laravel when user_id is required and taken using Auth

Tags: laravel

I have a simple form a user fills out with some basic information.  That form is received and a model row is created with the validated data AND the user_id which is found using Auth::id().  The user_id column is a foreign_key in the table.  The problem I have is that I don't know how to create the new model row with the proper user_id.

I have the following in my controller

```
  public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
    $test = Auth::check();
    $user = Auth::id();

    if ($test == false){
        return redirect('/login');
    }

     else {

            $data = request()->validate ([
                'first_name' => '',
                'last_name' => '',
                'phone' => '',
                'email' => '',
                'city' => '',
                'state' => '',
                'zip_code' => '',
                'procedure' => '',
                'travel' => '',
                'timetable' => '',

            ]);



            $procedurePlan = ProcedurePlan::create($data);
            // $procedurePlan = new ProcedurePlan;
            $procedurePlan->user_id=$user;
            $procedurePlan->save();
            $procedurePlan->update($data);

            return redirect ('/procedure-planner');

        }
}
```

Comment: Is all that validate fields belongs to `procedurePlan`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$procedurePlan = ProcedurePlan::create(['user_id' => $user]);
$procedurePlan->update($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Save it only once:

```php
$procedurePlan = new ProcedurePlan($data);
$procedurePlan->user_id = Auth::id();
$procedurePlan->save();
```